# Autocomplete on GraphQl query with nuxt-graphql-client

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, nuxt.js, intellisense

Is there any way to have intellisence/autocomplete on GraphQl queries, when using nuxt-graphql-client in VS CODE?

[image]

Comment: Not directly related to Nuxt. There is an Apollo Studio (forgot the exact name) + some extensions that may fetch your resolvers and provide you IntelliSense.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Apollo plugin for VS Code